# Hadoop 2.2.0 Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, hadoop

I have installed hadoop-2.2.0 (single node cluser) and maven3.3.1 on my pc. I want to program MapReduce code in eclipse. So my questions are:

1. What is the relationship between mapreduce and maven?
2. How do I debug the code in eclipse? A tutorial says that I should first install a hadoop eclipse plugin in an old version, but it seems there isn't a plugin for the new version hadoop-2.2.0. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is no direct relationship between maven and hadoop

   Apache Maven is a software project management and comprehension tool. Based on the concept of a project object model (POM), Maven can manage a project's build, reporting and documentation from a central piece of information.

   And using maven you can download dependencies to develop hadoop/mapreduce project

   http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/
2. There is no eclipse plugin for 2.2.0, it's still in development stage but you can try IntelliJ IDEA, which is also a nice development tool for java.

   http://vichargrave.com/intellij-project-for-building-hadoop-the-definitive-guide-examples/

Answer (score 2):

I have compiled the eclipse plugin from https://github.com/winghc/hadoop2x-eclipse-plugin and uploaded the final jar file on github ( https://github.com/abhishekgoel137/hadoop-eclipse-plugins ).

will save you some time to compile.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Eclipse fails to detect it though.

Answer (score 1):

you can download and compile the  eclipse plugin for hadoop 2.2.0 from github at https://github.com/winghc/hadoop2x-eclipse-plugin