# MRUnit on windows without hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera, mapr, mrunit

I am looking to see if there is a way to run hadoop Mapreduce unit tests in Windows without having a hadoop setup.  Does MRUnit run on windows (without cygwin) in Eclipse as a Java maven project?

Thanks
Srivatsan Nallazhagappan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run standalone `MRUnit` tests. All you need are a few dependencies in your pom. I just did a quick little test and these are the only dependencies I needed to run a successful test. Just a simple test with hard coded values. No cywin, no hadoop setup, just the dependencies.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0_25</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-yarn-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.mrunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>mrunit</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <classifier>hadoop2</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

As far as running a setup without cygwin, that's possible also. Have a look at [this site](http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/38/build-install-configure-run-apache-hadoop-2.2.0-microsoft-windows-os) and [this site](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hadoop2OnWindows) for help with building and installing hadoop for windows *without* cywin.

Also another helpful tool is the hadoop plugin for eclipse. You can see a [compiled version here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22046684/2587435). It's pretty easy to use. You can get some help on how to use it [here](http://v-lad.org/Tutorials/Hadoop/23%20-%20create%20the%20project.html)

Comment: Thanks.It works great. This is cool, I see Mrunit also supports distributed cache. Just an extension of my original question (will create a separate post if required), I assume mrunit cannot mock if there are hdfs read/write calls within the map/set up method(I understand its not generally recommended, unfortunately I have read calls in my setup method).

Comment: You can use a `MiniMRCluster` and `MiniDFSCluster` as discussed [here](http://grepalex.com/2012/10/20/hadoop-unit-testing-with-minimrcluster/). You'll need the `hadoop-test-x.y.z.jar` for this. I've just set it up in eclipse. Let me know if you want further information

Comment: Thanks. Will try them out. Found that Mrunit does not seem to have a complete support of distributed cache (symlink feature for example is not available) atleast in the 1.0.0 version I am using.